# How do I change the text size of a GtkLabel using gtk_label_set_attributes?

Tags: c, user-interface, text, label, gtk

I have this:

```
GtkWidget *const Label = gtk_label_new("Welcome");
gtk_label_set_attributes((GtkLabel *)Label, ({
    PangoAttrList *const Attrs = pango_attr_list_new();
    pango_attr_list_insert(Attrs, pango_attr_size_new(36));
    Attrs;
}));
gtk_container_add((GtkContainer *)Window, Label);
```

I am attempting to change the text size of a `GtkLabel` without using some kind of markup language that needs to be parsed

## Current Result:

No text is displayed

## Expected Result:

Text is displayed as if used `gtk_label_set_markup("<span font=\"36\">Welcome</span>");`

*How should I proceed?*

## Update:

The following works *to display the text*:

```
GtkWidget *const Label = gtk_label_new(GameDirStr+2);
PangoAttrList *const Attrs = pango_attr_list_new();
PangoAttribute *const SizeAttr = pango_attr_size_new(72*PANGO_SCALE);
pango_attr_list_insert(Attrs, SizeAttr);
// pango_attribute_destroy(SizeAttr); // SEGFAULT
gtk_label_set_attributes((GtkLabel *)Label, Attrs);
pango_attr_list_unref(Attrs); // WORKS
pango_attribute_destroy(SizeAttr); // SEGFAULT even after the attributes were added to the label
gtk_container_add((GtkContainer *)Window, Label);
```

***BUT*** the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Text-Attributes.html) states that I should eventually free them using `pango_attribute_destroy()`, but doing so causes a segfault, even after I added them to the list

How do I properly deallocate them?

The process of changing the text size using Pango attributes also includes the expected practices such as freeing the memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the attributes should be a pango font descriptor. You can set the size, family, etc. and then add this to the attribute list. See the following code:

```
attrlist = pango_attr_list_new();

PangoFontDescription * font_desc = pango_font_description_new();
pango_font_description_set_size(font_desc, 36 * PANGO_SCALE);
PangoAttribute * attr = pango_attr_font_desc_new(font_desc);

pango_attr_list_insert(attrlist, attr);

gtk_label_set_attributes((GtkLabel *) Label, attrlist);
```

Comment: In this case, what is `pango_attr_size_new(36)` anyway?

Comment: I figured out I don't need a font description, just pango_scale is enough

Comment: @user15318445 Glad you figured it out. If you end up needing font faces and stuff pango_font_description comes in handy. For the record, I use gtkmm for C++ for my gtk development, so seeing gtk code in C is a bit out of my depth. I find GUI elements and such work out much better using an object-oriented approach.

Comment: I see, also I have another problem, I am supposed to call `pango_attribute_destroy()` to free memory, but doing so causes a segfault, any ideas?

Comment: @user15318445 segfault is caused by access to an invalid or out of bounds address. Make sure you pass a valid address. That is, make sure you pass a pointer (not a value), and the pointer is in the scope. If you wrap your attribute creation in a function or in curly braces, you cannot free it outside.

Comment: I do all that, I pass the pointer for the same attribute, I moved it out of the curly braces, added it to the list, then called `pango_attribute_destroy()`, but it still causes a segfault

Comment: @user15318445 Interesting, something must not be right. The pointer must not be valid. I can't really find a solution without seeing code. Recommendation - check if the pointer is NULL. Never call any freeing method on a NULL pointer, this is always a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

> BUT the documentation states that I should eventually free them using pango_attribute_destroy(), but doing so causes a segfault, even after I added them to the list

> How do I properly deallocate them?

You don't have to. The attribute list owns the attributes passed to  `pango_attr_list_insert()` See [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/unstable/pango-Text-Attributes.html#pango-attr-list-insert) (`PangoAttribute *attr` is `[transfer full]`). So you no longer owns the `PangoAttribute` unless you add additional references.  Also, see related [gi documentation](https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annotations/giannotations.html#memory-and-lifecycle-management)

Comment: Is it valid to reuse a `PangoAttrList` on multiple labels?

Comment: I don't know. But as per `GtkLabel` documentation, the attributes can change for other reasons (like some property changes, or may be state changes like hover?), so it's better not to reuse

Answer (score 0):

There is one big issue:

Destroy the attributes AFTER they have been added to the label. Trying to set attributes to a label that are NULL will cause a segmentation fault.

So, in short, create the attributes, create the list, add the attributes to the list, set the list of attributes to the label, delete the attributes with attribute destroy, delete the list with pango list unref.

Comment: I did it in this order, but I still have a segfault

Answer (score 0):

About using `pango_attribute_destroy()`, I figured out that the answer is to not do it, because [`pango_attr_list_unref()`](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Text-Attributes.html#pango-attr-list-unref) will free any contained attributes in the list automatically

> Decrease the reference count of the given attribute list by one. If the result is zero, free the attribute list **and the attributes it contains**.